# Cannot access content from icloud in imovie

Tags: iphone, icloud, imovie

I am new to iMovie. I have several photos/videos on my iphone, which is already synced in iCloud. Now on my Macbook with iMovie I would like to merge/edit them. But I am unable to access them from iCloud inside iMovie.

Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: How are you trying to do it now?

Comment: And do you have iCloud Photo Syncing set up on your Mac?

Comment: No, I guess no. Can you please guide me in how to do that ?

Comment: @Joy https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205207